# Nested formArray controls' of null

Tags: angular, angular-material

I tried angular reactive formArray inside another formArray. but, i got unfortunately **error** Controls' is null.

Beginner at angular. Help me.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormArray, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

interface eventPlatform {
  value: string;
  viewValue: string;
}

interface resourcePerson {
  value: string;
  viewValue: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-event',
  templateUrl: './create-event.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create-event.component.css']
})
export class CreateEventComponent implements OnInit {
  firstFormGroup: FormGroup;
  secondFormGroup: FormGroup;

  eventPlatforms: eventPlatform[] = [
    {value: 'Google Meet', viewValue: 'Google Meet'},
    {value: 'Zoom', viewValue: 'Zoom'},
  ];

  resourcePersons: resourcePerson[] = [
    {value: '1', viewValue: '1'},
    {value: '2', viewValue: '2'},
  ];

  deleteResourceButton = true;
  deleteContactButton = false;

  constructor(
    private _formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.firstFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      eventDepartmentCtrl: ['', Validators.required],
      eventNameCtrl: ['', Validators.required],
      eventPlatformCtrl: ['', Validators.required],
      eventStartTimeCtrl: ['', Validators.required],
      eventEndTimeCtrl: ['', Validators.required],
      eventEventKeyTakeawaysCtrl: ['', Validators.required],
      contactPersonCtrl: this._formBuilder.array([this.getContactPerson()], [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1), Validators.maxLength(2)]),
      resourcePersonCtrl: this._formBuilder.array([this.getResourcePerson()], [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1), Validators.maxLength(3)]),
    });
    this.secondFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      secondCtrl: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }

  addEvent(){
    this.router.navigate(['/portal']);
  }

  addDraft(){
    this.router.navigate(['/portal']);
  }

  cancelCreate(){
    this.router.navigate(['/portal']);
  }

  // Resource Person
  get resourcePersonArray() {
    return <FormArray>this.firstFormGroup.get("resourcePersonCtrl");
  }

  addResourcePerson(){
    this.resourcePersonArray.push(this.getResourcePerson());
  }

  deleteResourcePerson(index){
    this.resourcePersonArray.removeAt(index);
  }

  getResourcePerson(){
    return this._formBuilder.group({
      personNameCtrl: ['', Validators.required],
      personDesignationCtrl: ['', Validators.required],
      personCompanyCtrl: ['', Validators.required],
      socialMediaCtrl: this._formBuilder.array([this.getSocialMedia()], [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1), Validators.maxLength(2)])
    })
  }

  // Contact Person
  get contactPersonArray() {
    return <FormArray>this.firstFormGroup.get("contactPersonCtrl");
  }

  addContactPerson(){
    this.contactPersonArray.push(this.getContactPerson());
  }

  deleteContactPerson(index){
    this.contactPersonArray.removeAt(index);
  }

  getContactPerson(){
    return this._formBuilder.group({
      contactNameCtrl: ['', Validators.required],
      contactNumberCtrl: ['', Validators.required],
    })
  }

  // Social media
  get socialMediaArray() {
    return <FormArray>this.firstFormGroup.get("socialMediaCtrl");
  }

  addSocialMedia(){
    this.socialMediaArray.push(this.getSocialMedia());
  }

  deleteSocialMedia(index){
    this.socialMediaArray.removeAt(index);
  }

  getSocialMedia(){
    return this._formBuilder.group({
      socialMediaNameCtrl: ['', Validators.required],
      socialMediaLinkCtrl: ['', Validators.required],
    })
  }
  
}



<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center start" class="mat-typography">
    <div fxFlex="50%" fxFlex.xs="95%">
        <br>
        <h3 class="mat-subheading-2 white-text">Create New Event</h3>
        <div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
            <mat-vertical-stepper linear #stepper>
                <mat-step [stepControl]="firstFormGroup">
                    <form [formGroup]="firstFormGroup">
                        <ng-template matStepLabel>Fill out</ng-template>
                        <p>Event Details</p>
                        <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="right" fxLayoutGap="25px" class="mat-typography">
                            <mat-form-field fxFlex="100%" appearance="outline">
                                <mat-label>Department</mat-label>
                                <input matInput placeholder="Department name" formControlName="eventDepartmentCtrl"
                                    required>
                            </mat-form-field>
                        </div>
                        <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center" fxLayoutGap="25px" class="mat-typography">
                            <mat-form-field fxFlex="50%" appearance="outline">
                                <mat-label>Event name</mat-label>
                                <input matInput placeholder="Event name" formControlName="eventNameCtrl" required>
                            </mat-form-field>
                            <mat-form-field fxFlex="50%" appearance="outline">
                                <mat-label>Platform</mat-label>
                                <mat-select formControlName="eventPlatformCtrl" required>
                                    <mat-option *ngFor="let eventPlatform of eventPlatforms"
                                        [value]="eventPlatform.value">
                                        {{eventPlatform.viewValue}}
                                    </mat-option>
                                </mat-select>
                            </mat-form-field>
                        </div>
                        <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center" fxLayoutGap="25px" class="mat-typography">
                            <mat-form-field fxFlex="50%" appearance="outline">
                                <mat-label>Event Start</mat-label>
                                <input matInput type="datetime-local" formControlName="eventStartTimeCtrl"
                                    placeholder="Start date">
                            </mat-form-field>
                            <mat-form-field fxFlex="50%" appearance="outline">
                                <mat-label>Event End</mat-label>
                                <input matInput type="datetime-local" formControlName="eventEndTimeCtrl"
                                    placeholder="Start date">
                            </mat-form-field>
                        </div>
                        <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center" fxLayoutGap="25px" class="mat-typography">
                            <mat-form-field fxFlex="100%" appearance="outline">
                                <mat-label>Event Key takeaways</mat-label>
                                <textarea matInput formControlName="eventEventKeyTakeawaysCtrl"
                                    placeholder="Event Key Takeaways">
                                </textarea>
                            </mat-form-field>
                        </div>
                        <mat-divider></mat-divider>
                        <br>
                        <p>Contact Person Details</p>
                        <br>
                        <div formArrayName="contactPersonCtrl">
                            <div *ngFor="let item of contactPersonArray.controls; let i = index;" [formGroupName]="i">
                                <p>Contact Person: {{i+1}}</p>
                                <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="right" fxLayoutGap="25px" class="mat-typography">
                                    <mat-form-field fxFlex="50%" appearance="outline">
                                        <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
                                        <input matInput placeholder="Person Name" formControlName="contactNameCtrl"
                                            required>
                                    </mat-form-field>
                                    <mat-form-field fxFlex="50%" appearance="outline">
                                        <mat-label>Phone Number</mat-label>
                                        <input matInput placeholder="Person Number" formControlName="contactNumberCtrl"
                                            required>
                                    </mat-form-field>
                                    <div class="button-padding">
                                        <button mat-icon-button color="primary"
                                            *ngIf="contactPersonArray.controls.length < 2" (click)="addContactPerson()">
                                            <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
                                        </button>
                                        <button mat-icon-button color="warn"
                                            *ngIf="contactPersonArray.controls.length > 1"
                                            (click)="deleteContactPerson(i)">
                                            <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <mat-divider></mat-divider>
                        <br>
                        <p>Resource Person Details</p>
                        <br>
                        <div formArrayName="resourcePersonCtrl">
                            <div *ngFor="let person of resourcePersonArray.controls; let i = index;" [formGroupName]="i">
                                <p>Resource Person: {{i+1}}</p>
                                <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center" fxLayoutGap="25px" class="mat-typography">
                                    <mat-form-field fxFlex="50%" appearance="outline">
                                        <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
                                        <input matInput placeholder="Person Name" formControlName="personNameCtrl"
                                            required>
                                    </mat-form-field>
                                    <mat-form-field fxFlex="50%" appearance="outline">
                                        <mat-label>Designation</mat-label>
                                        <input matInput placeholder="Person Designation"
                                            formControlName="personDesignationCtrl" required>
                                    </mat-form-field>
                                </div>
                                <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center" fxLayoutGap="25px" class="mat-typography">
                                    <mat-form-field fxFlex="100%" appearance="outline">
                                        <mat-label>Company</mat-label>
                                        <input matInput placeholder="Person Company" formControlName="personCompanyCtrl"
                                            required>
                                    </mat-form-field>
                                </div>
                                <div formArrayName="socialMediaCtrl">
                                    <div *ngFor="let social of socialMediaArray.controls; let j = index;"
                                        [formGroupName]="j">
                                        <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="right" fxLayoutGap="25px"
                                            class="mat-typography">
                                            <mat-form-field fxFlex="50%" appearance="outline">
                                                <mat-label>Social Media</mat-label>
                                                <input matInput placeholder="Social Media Name"
                                                    formControlName="socialMediaNameCtrl" required>
                                            </mat-form-field>
                                            <mat-form-field fxFlex="50%" appearance="outline">
                                                <mat-label>Social Media Link</mat-label>
                                                <input matInput placeholder="Social Mediua Link"
                                                    formControlName="socialMediaLinkCtrl" required>
                                            </mat-form-field>
                                            <div class="button-padding">
                                                <button mat-icon-button color="primary"
                                                    *ngIf="socialMediaArray.controls.length < 2"
                                                    (click)="addSocialMedia()">
                                                    <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
                                                </button>
                                                <button mat-icon-button color="warn"
                                                    *ngIf="socialMediaArray.controls.length > 1"
                                                    (click)="deleteSocialMedia(j)">
                                                    <mat-icon>delete</mat-icon>
                                                </button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="button-padding">
                                    <button mat-raised-button *ngIf="resourcePersonArray.controls.length < 3"
                                        (click)="addResourcePerson()">Add</button>
                                    <button mat-raised-button color="warn"
                                        *ngIf="resourcePersonArray.controls.length > 1"
                                        (click)="deleteResourcePerson(i)">Delete</button>
                                </div>
                                <br>
                                <br>
                                <mat-divider></mat-divider>
                                <br>
                                <br>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div>
                            <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </mat-step>
                <mat-step [stepControl]="secondFormGroup">
                    <form [formGroup]="secondFormGroup">
                        <ng-template matStepLabel>Fill out your address</ng-template>
                        <mat-form-field>
                            <mat-label>Captcha</mat-label>
                            <input matInput formControlName="secondCtrl" placeholder="Ex. 1 Main St, New York, NY"
                                required>
                        </mat-form-field>
                        <div>
                            <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Previous</button>
                            <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </mat-step>
                <mat-step>
                    <ng-template matStepLabel>Done</ng-template>
                    <p>You are now done.</p>
                    <div class="button-padding">
                        <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Previous</button>
                        <button mat-button (click)="stepper.reset()">Reset</button>
                        <button mat-button color="warn" (click)="cancelCreate()">Cancel</button>
                        <button mat-raised-button (click)="addDraft()">Save Draft</button>
                        <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="addEvent()">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </mat-step>
            </mat-vertical-stepper>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I tried angular reactive formArray inside another formArray. but, i got unfortunately **error** Controls' is null.

Beginner at angular. Help me.

I tried angular reactive formArray inside another formArray. but, i got unfortunately **error** Controls' is null.

Beginner at angular. Help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  // Social media
  get socialMediaArray() {
    //  return []; //  to test it uncomment this line 
    return <FormArray>this.firstFormGroup.get("socialMediaCtrl");
  }
```

This part of your code where Template is trying to get the **socialMediaCtrl** and use it's controls for ngFor and your form (**firstFormGroup**) doesn't have **socialMediaCtrl** control

```
    this.firstFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      eventDepartmentCtrl: ['', Validators.required],
      eventNameCtrl: ['', Validators.required],
      eventPlatformCtrl: ['', Validators.required],
      eventStartTimeCtrl: ['', Validators.required],
      eventEndTimeCtrl: ['', Validators.required],
      eventEventKeyTakeawaysCtrl: ['', Validators.required],
      contactPersonCtrl: this._formBuilder.array([this.getContactPerson()], [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1), Validators.maxLength(2)]),
      resourcePersonCtrl: this._formBuilder.array([this.getResourcePerson()], [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1), Validators.maxLength(3)]),
    });
```

Comment: thanks for your response.  @Eric Aska I tried return [], it works fine. but why? i connect formArray like this: resourcePersonCtrl -> this.getResourcePerson() -> socialMediaCtrl .

Comment: It's very clear why it's happening. your formGroup "this.firstFormGroup" doesn't have a control named "socialMediaCtrl". your formGroup available controls are: eventDepartmentCtrl, eventNameCtrl, eventPlatformCtrl, eventStartTimeCtrl,

Comment: change this line as follow. <div *ngFor="let social of person.get('socialMediaCtrl').controls; let j = index;"
                                        [formGroupName]="j">

Comment: @eric i tried console.log(<FormArray>this.firstFormGroup.get("resourcePersonCtrl")); log showing value: Array(1)
0:
personCompanyCtrl: ""
personDesignationCtrl: ""
personNameCtrl: ""
socialMediaCtrl: Array(1)
0:
socialMediaLinkCtrl: ""
socialMediaNameCtrl: "".

Comment: @Chellappanவ i tried but error showing 'controls' is not defined.

Comment: I have tried to reprodocue issue in stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-necjq4. it's working fine.

Comment: @Chellappanவ i tried thi *ngFor="let social of person.get('socialMediaCtrl')['controls']; let j = index; it works fine. thank you. Good day.